# Android weird color behaviour

Tags: android, android-xml

The setup and the problem is the following:

- Setup: I have well defined colors that I got from Inkscape (the program that I create visuals)
- Problem: The colros look different
- What I tried: hacking the android theme that I'm using, but it does not help me

Color xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <!-- Menu list -->
   <color name="list_item_title">#000</color>
   <color name="list_background">#FFafc6e9</color>
   <color name="list_background_pressed">#FF2A52BE</color>
   <color name="list_divider">#FF92A1CF</color>

  <!--  Counter -->
  <color name="counter_text_bg">#626262</color>
  <color name="counter_text_color">#c5c4c4</color>  
 </resources>
```

Thema xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  </style>
</resources>
```

The designed colors:

[image]

Comment: So what is the problem?  Tell or show us what the colors actually look like.

Comment: So I took a screen shot an it looks the same, so the color is the same, as in the program. Probably the phones display is different how can I handle this?

Comment: I now the App Thema can also modify it. BUT In this case only the swipe menu shows this color error. The normal LinearLayer with a background has the good color.

Comment: Wait, you're saying you looked at the colors on two completely different screens, with your eyeballs, and they looked different? Did this really come as a surprise to you?

Comment: I say part of it looks different. I use standard themas.